# Windbg - <HRESULT 0x80004002>, invalid cast, alias as vs. aS

Tags: casting, alias, windbg

Good day,

I have a Windbg script that iterates around the frames of a stack using a `.do` loop. For each frame it uses `!for_each_local` and `$spat ("@#Local","foo")` to match for things I'm interested in getting an initial look at. I then use `dx @$t2 =` to assign and finally print out what I'm interested in, i.e. `dx @$t2 = ((foobase*) this)->m_current->m_name` - mostly this works fine.

Every now and again, there'll be a `this` in a frame that can't be cast successfully with the `dx`, so it's like `barbase` it would need, not `foobase`... the `dx` seems OK because I've wrapped it in a `.foreach (output { dx @$t2 = ((foobase*) this)->m_current->m_name }) {}` so it ends up containing *something* that causes the script to exit (that's despite trying a `.catch`).

At first I didn't really realise what was going on, but doing a `.printf "%ma\n", @$t2` helped me to ascertain the contents is `<HRESULT 0x80004002>` which I *think* implies invalid cast - which, if so, makes perfect sense. My script line is using `foobase` when it would need `barbase`.

**If** I'm correct, what I'm looking for is a way to check that, before I delve into the script further and try to access details I know will cause the script to exit.

I *seem* to have come up with a convoluted way of doing it... but I wanted to ask if there was anything better...

```
.frame 0a     $$ a frame with barbase, not foobase
dx @$t2 = ((foobase*) this)->m_name
.printf "%ma\n", @$t2     $$ prints <HRESULT 0x80004002>
as /c CastCheck .printf "%ma", @$t2
.if ($spat(@"${CastCheck}","<HRESULT 0x80004002>") = 1) { .printf "yes" } .else { .printf "no" }     $$ prints yes
```

Is there a way to check if `$t2` contains an indicator of invalid cast without using an alias?

I ask this because using the alias has caused me much confusion... in my script (for it to work, and it does seem to work quite well) I've had to use `aS` instead of `as` (I can use `as` fine from the Command Window, and I don't really understand *why* I need to change to `aS` from reading the documentation) and I also need to end the line with a semi-colon (unlike any other line in my script) and I need to use `ad /q CastCheck;` immediately before the `aS`, and then quickly afterwards, otherwise the alias seems to get lost, somehow... so you can tell the use of this alias has caused me a little trouble.

So, is there either **a)** an easy way to pre-check whether what I'm looking at is `foobase` or `barbase`, or **b)** post-check after the cast attempt whether `$t2` contains this `<HRESULT 0x80004002>`? If I do a `.printf "%d", @$t2` it shows `5`... does `5` represent something too?

Or, indeed, any other ideas (or questions).

**EDIT:**

I'm going to *try* and illustrate what I mean with 2 short runs of code done in the Command Window... where frame 00 contains a `this` that *can* be cast to `foobase` and then the .`printf` works nicely, and where frame 0a contains a `this` that's a `barbase` (but my script still doesn't expect it and I want to be able to cater for it)... the `dx` still puts *something* in `$t10`... I want to be able to detect that it's garbage (or pre-detect I shouldn't even try the `dx`, if `this` is `barbase`, as it's pointless and I'm not interested in it anyway).

```
0:038> .frame 00
00 00000006`3e2bc930 00007ffe`926293a8 BlahBlahBlah 
0:038> dx @$t10 = ((foobase *) this)->m_name
@$t10 = ((foobase *) this)->m_name                 : 0x869c7b8 : "nice string" [Type: char *]
0:038> .printf "%ma\n", @$t10
nice string
```

This is where the `this` is a `barbase`, and doesn't even have a `m_name`:

```
0:038> .frame 0a
0a 00000006`3e2bd220 00007ffe`91ec7780 BlahBlahBlah 
0:038> dx @$t10 = ((foobase *) this)->m_name
@$t10 = ((foobase *) this)->m_name                 : 0x2265646f00000005 : "--- memory read error at address 0x2265646f`00000005 ---" [Type: char *]
0:038> .printf "%ma\n", @$t10
<HRESULT 0x80004002>
```

When put inside a loop I've found that the script will exit with a `Memory access error` on frame 0a when I try to check the length of the string I *believe* to have been returned by `dx`.

Basically, in the second block I want a way of either checking `$t10` for something that is **not** a nice string (probably this `<HRESULT 0x80004002>`?) or, even better, not doing the `dx` and `.printf` at all, because I was able to check before that `this` was a `barbase`, not a `foobase`.

Is that making any more sense, or should I start again?

Comment: can you edit in something that can be reproduced  it would make attempting to answer a bit more easy rather than grappling with vague descriptions

Comment: Attempted that! Apologies if it's made it worse.

Comment: I probably need a way to do an `.if` and `$spat` to differentiate between these... `0:038> .frame 00
00 000000063e2bc930 00007ffe926293a8 BlahBlahBlah
0:038> dv /t this
class foobase * this = 0x0000000008622c10
0:038> .frame 0a
0a 000000063e2bd220 00007ffe91ec7780 BlahBlahBlah 
0:038> dv /t this
class barbase * this = 0x00000000194dacf0` but how?

Comment: C++ does not maintain type information for its objects. So you can't tell two memory blocks of 16 bytes apart. You can cast everything, but it might not work. In your case, it does not work. Why don't you as the programmer know whether you have a foobase or barbase inside the method BlahBlahBlah?

Comment: Couple of ideas to throw into the mix!: 1). Can the assignment with cast be done through `r?`? And if so, 1.a) Does it work as said in the help page: `Causes the pseudo-register to acquire *typed* information`? 1.b)  Does doing the assignment in 2 step (first this, and then member) help somewhat? 2). Would you be able to figure out the actual "this" from investigating their v-tables? foobase, and barbase would have different v-tables? 3) `5` is probably offset (?) of "m_name", and when you do `printf` with `%d` it assumed 32-bit argument and wrote the lower portion of `0x2265646f00000005`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - sadly, I don't have **intimate** knowledge of the many, many hundreds of methods that _might_ appear in a stack... most times the `this` that's present _does_ contain what I want, sometimes not and if I'm doing it manually it's easy enough to see that, what I want is a way for my script to detect this and then not bother doing what it would _normally_ do. I thought it might be by assigning the result of `dv /t this` to an alias and then doing `$spat` on it... it seems I can't get that to work reliably either. I realise that I am learning on the job with this stuff so to speak.

Comment: @OzgurH - thanks, I think the cast itself, via `dx`, is kinda fine, it's working and not throwing an error, it's just that when I try to access what I want to extract `this->m_name` it's either there or not, and, if not, the script seems to have a good old moan about it (despite me attempting to use `.catch`)... so, really, I'm looking for a **either** a way of detecting the method in the frame loop and if it's one I know doesn't have `this->m_name` then I can just skip it **or** of detecting the actual class of `this`, like `dv /t this` shows. Maybe I need to do this with an alias after all?

Answer (score 1):

well you attempted but it is still vague

can you explain what is necessity to do .frame
and then dx  this ??

you can cast any address to any type

for example in the first run I am casting the this to a proper type and enumerating all Frames

in the next run I am casting to a bogus type and enumerating

in both of this only one frame has a this pointer

when it is proper type it returns proper member

when it is bogus well it returns bogus stuff

```
0:000> !for_each_frame dx ((Student *) this)->Name
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
00 000000c5`d6f6f8c0 00007ff7`2818117c thisptr!Student::PrintStudent+0x9 [f:\src\thisptr\thisptr.cpp @ 20] 
((Student *) this)->Name                 : 0x7ff7282153e0 : "dave" [Type: char *]
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
01 000000c5`d6f6f8f0 00007ff7`281b6c20 thisptr!main+0x2c [f:\src\thisptr\thisptr.cpp @ 33] 
Error: Unable to bind name 'this'
```

it found a this but it cant find the Member Name

```
0:000> !for_each_frame dx ((ntdll!_EPROCESS *) this)->Name
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
00 000000c5`d6f6f8c0 00007ff7`2818117c thisptr!Student::PrintStudent+0x9 [f:\src\thisptr\thisptr.cpp @ 20] 
Error: Unable to bind name 'Name' <<<<<<
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
01 000000c5`d6f6f8f0 00007ff7`281b6c20 thisptr!main+0x2c [f:\src\thisptr\thisptr.cpp @ 33] 
Error: Unable to bind name 'this'
```

btw you know what type a this pointer is already so why are you casting it ??

you can find the type of this ptr with various commands some of which are shown below

```
0:000> dx this
this                 : 0xc5d6f6f910 [Type: Student *] <<<
    [+0x000] Roll             : 1 [Type: int]
    [+0x008] Name             : 0x7ff7282153e0 : "dave" [Type: char *]
    [+0x010] Marks            : 72.300000 [Type: double]


0:000> ?? this 
class Student * 0x000000c5`d6f6f910  <<<
   +0x000 Roll             : 0n1
   +0x008 Name             : 0x00007ff7`282153e0  "dave"
   +0x010 Marks            : 72.299999999999997158 


0:000> x /t this
000000c5`d6f6f8f0 class Student * this = 0x000000c5`d6f6f910  <<<


0:000> x /v /t this
prv local  000000c5`d6f6f8f0    8 class Student * this = 0x000000c5`d6f6f910

0:000> dt this 
Local var @ 0xc5d6f6f8f0 Type Student*
0x000000c5`d6f6f910 
   +0x000 Roll             : 0n1
   +0x008 Name             : 0x00007ff7`282153e0  "dave"
   +0x010 Marks            : 72.299999999999997158 


0:000> dt /v this 
Local var [AddrFlags 90  AddrOff 0000000000000030  Reg/Val rsp (7)] @ 0xc5d6f6f8f0 Type Student*
0x000000c5`d6f6f910 class Student, 5 elements, 0x18 bytes
   +0x000 Roll             : 0n1
   +0x008 Name             : 0x00007ff7`282153e0  "dave"
   +0x010 Marks            : 72.299999999999997158 
   <function> Student     void (
    int, 
    char*, 
    double)+000000c5`d6f6f910
   <function> PrintStudent     void ( void )+000000c5`d6f6f910

0:000> dt /v /t this 
Local var [AddrFlags 90  AddrOff 0000000000000030  Reg/Val rsp (7)] @ 0xc5d6f6f8f0 Type Student*
0x000000c5`d6f6f910 class Student, 5 elements, 0x18 bytes
   +0x000 Roll             : 0n1
   +0x008 Name             : 0x00007ff7`282153e0  "dave"
   +0x010 Marks            : 72.299999999999997158 
   <function> Student     void (
    int, 
    char*, 
    double)+000000c5`d6f6f910
   <function> PrintStudent     void ( void )+000000c5`d6f6f910
```

Comment: I think you've illustrated better than me in your first code block. Yes, I can work fine with frame 00, and frame 01 puts out the `unable to bind` error. What I was looking for - in my script's loop - was a means of avoiding that being spat out, or the script exiting deeper down inside logic, by avoiding even checking a frame where I knew there would not be a `this->m_name`... `Name` in your example, in that case the output from my script is nice and clean, without various meaningless(? - maybe uninteresting is a better word) errors being spat out.

Comment: Thank you for illustrating the various ways of obtaining the type... I knew most of these already, but not all - certainly not `x /v /t this`. Ideally, for cleanliness of script output again - without all the extraneous information, I had wanted a way of getting _just_ the type... and I think `dv /t this` is the cleanest so far - what it returns is manageable, but I'd still love to be able to parse that resulting string to remove `class` from the front and anything beyond `*`... again, it's all for presentation within a script.

Comment: as I stated in your other question dump all this text parsing crap and embrace javascript  i will add another answer below

Comment: Thanks! I do not mind using the obtuse stuff... the vanilla... I learn a little bit more each time. ;-) I might not be as productive as I could be using Javascript, maybe, but it appeals a lot when you eventually get what you want working. I always appreciate your input to these questions.

Answer (score 0):

adding another answer to emphasize the usage of javascript instead of parsing text

javascript script support was added to windbg  quiet a long time back 
and it is being improved a lot

(to try the latest javascript additions use the windbg preview in latest windows 10 version)

x /v /t or dv /t  provides the type of the this pointer

javascript provides a targetType property for these object

here is how to use it

create a .js file foo.js with the contents below

```
function typethis ( somevar ) 
{
    host.diagnostics.debugLog( somevar.targetType ,  "\t" , JSON.stringify(somevar) , "\n"  )
}
```

in windbg do

```
.load jsprovider
.scriptload x:\..\\..\foo.js
dx @$scriptcontents.functionname(argument) to run the script
```

and the results will be

```
0:000> .load jsprovider
0:000> .scriptload f:\wdscr\typthis.js
JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'f:\wdscr\typthis.js'
0:000> dx @$scriptContents.typethis( this )
Student *   {"Roll":1,"Name":{},"Marks":72.3}
@$scriptContents.typethis( this )
```